# Error while inserting data to DB

Tags: mule, mule-component, anypoint-studio

The requirement is to parse the input xml and insert the data into db.

During DB insertion its throwing below error

```
********************************************************************************
Message               : Can't find bundle for base name META-INF.services.org.mule.i18n.db-messages, locale en_US (java.util.MissingResourceException). Message payload is of type: Order
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. Can't find bundle for base name META-INF.services.org.mule.i18n.db-messages, locale en_US (java.util.MissingResourceException)
  java.util.ResourceBundle:1564 (null)
2. Can't find bundle for base name META-INF.services.org.mule.i18n.db-messages, locale en_US (java.util.MissingResourceException). Message payload is of type: Order (org.mule.api.MessagingException)
  org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor:32 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/MessagingException.html)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name META-INF.services.org.mule.i18n.db-messages, locale en_US
        at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:1564)
        at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1387)
        at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:1082)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
```

Can you someone let me know the root cause of the issue.

flow configuration:

```
HTTP -> xml-tojaxb -> DB insert
```

Mule Server version: 3.7

Comment: mule runtime CE version